# Promise events global?

Tags: javascript, promise

`Ajax` have some global events like this:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
Loadding();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function () {
EndLoading();
});
```

Is `Promise` have global events?
Thank you

Comment: Promises are not events

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No there aren't. That is against the concept of Promises, since each of them represents a single Value, not an event or something alike.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are two events focused on event rejection. They are:

- [unhandledrejection](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-unhandledrejection)

  - Fired at global scope objects when a promise rejection goes unhandled
- [rejectionhandled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-rejectionhandled)

  - Fired at global scope objects when a previously-unhandled promise rejection becomes handled

They are not widely supported yet. Check compatibility table before using them.